# Minimum length of sequence such that every integer from 1 to n can be achieved as the sum of some contiguous subsequence

Tags: nt.number-theory, sequences-and-series, additive-combinatorics, integer-sequences

This question literally came to me in a fever dream last night, and it's frustrating me to no end. I'll try to explain it as best I can, but there may not be a satisfying answer; the best outcome might be someone finds something interesting about it.

Define an $n$-*good sequence of length* $k$ as any sequence $A=(a_1,a_2,...,a_k)$ such that for all integers $1\leq m \leq n$, there is some contiguous subsequence of $A$ that sums to $m$; that is, there exist $i\leq j$ such that $$m=\sum_{t=i}^{t=j}a_t.$$

Let $f(n)$ be the minimum $k$ such that there exists an $n$-good sequence of length $k$, and $g(k)$ be the maximum $n$ such that there exists an $n$-good sequence of length $k$.

Questions:

1. Is there any way to efficiently compute $f(n)$ and $g(k)$?
2. Even better, is there a closed formula for $f(n)$ and $g(k)$
3. Is there a way to construct a $g(k)$-good sequence of length $k$? i.e, how can one construct a sequence of length $k$ that attains the most possible consecutive positive integers as sums of its subsequences?

I've tried what are essentially brute-force approaches, but they're very slow. From these, as best as I can tell, $g(1)=1$, $g(2)=3$, $g(3)=6$, $g(4)=9$, $g(5)=13$, and $g(6)=18$, but there could be a problem with my approach.
It's natural that $k\leq g(k) \leq \frac{k(k+1)}{2}$, as there are $\frac{k(k+1)}{2}$ subsequences. Some construction might give better bounds here, but the ultimate goal would be a value, or an algorithm, for $g(k)$.

I'm excited to hear if anybody has any thoughts!

> **Update** As pointed out in the comments, these questions were extensively studied under the heading of [**sparse rulers**](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse_ruler), and many upper and lower bounds have been established.

Comment: A natural reformulation is to consider the sequence of partial sums $(s_i)$, then the requirement is that the set $\{s_j-s_i: 1\leq i\lt j\leq k\}$ contains $[n]$. Equivalently, $S\subset {\Bbb N}, |S|=k$ and $S-S\supseteq [n]$.

Comment: Actually, one needs to include the empty partial sum $s_0=0$, so $|S|=k+1$.

Comment: [Crossposted to math.stackexchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3296510/minimum-length-of-sequence-such-that-every-integer-from-1-to-n-can-be-achieved-a).

Comment: Are you assuming that the $a_i$ are positive integers? Maybe one can show that for the optimal sequences they have to be?

Comment: @quarague - I'd assumed they are, though this isn't based on anything. If you want to be safe in ignoring negative numbers, you could add $min(a_k)+1$ to each term and reformulate the requirement as "the sums of subsequences hit every integer $\alpha+1 \leq m \leq \alpha+n$", but that's not very satisfying...

Comment: Turns out this is equivalent to finding an incomplete sparse ruler, as pointed out here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3296510/minimum-length-of-sequence-such-that-every-integer-from-1-to-n-can-be-achieved-a#comment6781296_3296510 Wow!

Comment: See also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3279766/sparse-ruler-conjecture